# How to solve a 3x4 matrix in R without matrix command

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Looking to solve a 3x4 matrix without using the matrix command.

Looks like this:

```
 id = seq(1,4,1),
   x1 = c(3,44,12,25),
   x2 = c(14,-8,-14,8),
   x3 = c(22,38,13,4),
   y = c(7,11,2,9)
)
```

Is there a way to do this manually but without using "matrix" or transpose "t"?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would like to solve the system of equations in R? Seems like it would be much easier to do so using MATLAB or some online calculator for finding the rref of your matrix.

Comment: What's the meaning of "solve a 3x4 matrix"? What do you want to solve?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to solve Xb=y with b the unknown, in that case you could use optim.

```
X1=c(3, 44, 12, 25)
X2=c(14, -8, -14, 8)
X3=c(22, 38, 13, 4)
y=c(7, 11, 2, 9)
loss=function(x) {
  sum((X1*x[1] + X2 * x[2] +X3* x[3]-y)^2)
}
par=optim(c(1, 1, 1), loss, method="BFGS")$par
```

output

```
par
0.2300531 0.2550745 0.1005750

X1*par[1]+X2*par[2]+X3*par[3]
6.4738513 11.9035912  0.4970699  8.1942237
```